# Removing a document from array of documents in mongodb using c#

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I want to remove the highest value price document

```
{
    "name" : "Ryan",
    "price" : 6.5
}
```

from

```
db.books.find({_id:5}).pretty()
{
    "_id" : 5,
    "name" : "Big Book",
    "authors" : [
        {
            "name" : "Ryan",
            "price" : 5.5
        },
        {
            "name" : "Ryan",
            "price" : 6.5
        }
    ]
}
```

using c# driver

I have the removable document in c# front end in a collection.

But my following update statement is not removing the document.

```
var filter = new BsonDocument("_id", x._id);
var docToRemove = new BsonDocument("name", x.name);docToRemove.Add("price", x.price);
var update = Builders<Book>.Update.Pull("books.authors", docToRemove);
var result = await col.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(filter, update);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have required value in `x.price`?

I didn't test it for exactly your case, but try this:

```
var update = Builders<Book>.Update.PullFilter(p => p.authors,
                                              f => f.price == x.price);
var result = await collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(p => p._id == 5, update);
```

Comment: Cool sir, this one works. Thank you. In my case, as I needed to add 1 more condition to check along with price, I had to add an 
&&. So finally my update looks like this.

var update = Builders<Book>.Update.PullFilter(p => p.authors,
                                              f => (f.price == x.price && f.author == x.author ));